# how to read the elements of an array

Tags: batch-file, matrix

I have created a variable of type array but both the variable name and indexes are variables, And I would like to read them as a loop FOR: This is the code snippet that I can't solve

```
set /p dato=dato:
set /a indice+=1
for %%a in (%dato%) do (set %campo[%indice%]%=%%a)
for %%b in (%campo[%?%]%) do echo %%b
```

I can't understand How to tell the command to search all elements of that array.

Comment: isnt this what you're telling it to do `set %campo[%indice%]%=%%a`

Comment: What I need is to tell the FOR command to use that array to search for the elements

Comment: Please add question tag of the language in question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script)